# implementing bijective function in java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I want to implement an bijective function. 
From wikipedia a bijection (or bijective function or one-to-one correspondence) is a function between the elements of two sets, where every element of one set is paired with exactly one element of the other set, and every element of the other set is paired with exactly one element of the first set.
Is there any structure in Java to do that? If no how can I handle it efficiently?

Comment: I understand bijective functions and Java, but not what you are trying to achieve. What's your goal here?

Comment: use a Dictionary. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html

Comment: My goal is efficiency. I know both of them and can implement them but looking for ideas that is more efficient! This is my goal here not getting solution :)

Comment: I think he wants to make a hash function that has an output set the size of the input set, where each input to the function generates a unique output. In order to do this though, you would need to know the input set before creating the hash function.

Comment: I have a two set of numbers as an input and want to create a bijective function between them..

Comment: @Tarik read the docs: "NOTE: This class is obsolete."  Please use `HashMap` and the like rather than a class that has been obsolete for...probably at least a decade?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Point noted.

Answer (score 3):

You should try [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) form Guava.

Comment: A BiMap is a bidirectional Map, not a bijective function.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a problem, though.  The OP indicates that they get a set of numbers as input and want to be able to go between them.  A `BiMap` will let you do that.

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia:

*For a pairing between X and Y (where Y need not be different from X) to be a bijection, four properties must hold:*

- *each element of X must be paired with at least one element of Y*
- *no element of X may be paired with more than one element of Y*
- *each element of Y must be paired with at least one element of X*
- *and no element of Y may be paired with more than one element of X.*

Basically it is a standard function between two elements of different Collections that respects the 4 rules.

What you need to do is write a normal function that accept two parameters, one from first collection and one from second collection.

Then you need to apply that function to the correct pair of elements. This can be done ordering the first collection and the second collection.

So the solution is simple you have to use a `List` or if you prefer to use a `Set` you have to use a `LinkedHashSet` because the iteration order is predicted.